# following a link and returning back breaks mobile layout with viewport-fit=cover

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps, viewport

I am struggling with PWA I made. I have the html meta tag viewport-fit=cover, which make sure that on phones with a pinhole camera or cutout, the app will stretch around it. When the pwa is added to the phones home screen and opened it works, but when I open a link and return to the "app" the whole camera area is a black bar and the content doesn't stretch around it anymore. Does anyone have a clue if there is a way to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I have only written one PWA.  The whole App was one **javascript** file with one **html** page. Stepping through the app, did not change pages as the url remains constant. Therefore the back arrow does nothing on it.  You have to code that action yourself.

In this case, something is not getting initialised again.